# MouseArea onExited and onEntered infinite loop

Tags: qt, qml

I wanted to make a borderless window and add borders when mouse is inside that window/remove them when mouse is outside. So i added to my `ApplicationWindow`

```
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onEntered: {
                if(root.isBorderLessMode)
                    if(!(root.flags & Qt.FramelessWindowHint))
                        root.flags |= Qt.FramelessWindowHint;
        }
        onExited: {
                if(root.isBorderLessMode)
                    if((root.flags & Qt.FramelessWindowHint))
                    root.flags &= ~Qt.FramelessWindowHint;
        }
    }
```

Problem is when i move mouse inside that window application hangs for large amount of time and it is adding/removing border during that time. Why functions aren't called only once on enter and on exit?

Comment: Is it possible that when you set the `Qt.FramelessWindowHint` flag, the window shrinks, causing your mouse to then no longer be over the window?  Then the `onExited` event is fired and the `Qt.FramelessWindowHint` is set, causing the window to expand, and making the mouse be over the window again, causing `onEntered` to fire?  If so, you might need "debouncing" and "quiescent" logic or perhaps you need to only put the `hoverEnabled` and its logic inside the window borders itself?

Comment: `ApplicationWindow` has no `onEntered`/`onExited` events, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @folibis it does not but `MouseArea` has them and i made it fill parent which is `ApplicationWindow`